# Terminator & conda: Start Window in conda environment

Tags: command-line, bash, startup, anaconda

I am sitting here and cannot believe why it is so hard to make a terminator window use a conda environment at startup AND keep open for further commands.
I have tried different approaches but all lead to either one or another problem:

1. The bash is not accessible and stucked (when I did not insert `;bash` at the end of the command)
2. I was able to source conda and activate the environment, but using `;bash` afterwards closes the session with the environment I want and I get a new bash with the base environment.

(I achieved this with `source  ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate env_name`

What I want: A way of making terminator start an anaconda environment at startup, so I dont need to write manually `conda activate ...`

Thanks!